# Magento 2 Health Check File Not Found

Tags: php, magento2, health-check

is it possible to use **domain-name.com/health_check.php** instead of forward slash (/) only for our Magento 2 website's health check? we tried to input **/health_check.php** in AWS's target group health check but it shows unhealthy because Magento returns **file not found** when we tried to access the file publicly (the healty_check.php file exists in Magento's pub folder).
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using nginx and php-fpm to serve magento on aws ecs,
to achieve what you are trying I added health.conf to /etc/nginx/conf.d/

also the path in tg health check=/health_check.php

Root dir of magento will have pub/health_check.php
make sure to change your root dir location.

```html
health.conf

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/pub;

    location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```